# Batch File on Windows - Directory iteration

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, if-statement

I'm struggling with batch files, which I have never used before. Hope you guys can help me.

I want to iterate through a directory, and when directories in that directory contains a specific string; do an other process.

```
FOR /d %%d in (directory) (
   echo "Hello World"
)
pause
```

Thats all I have for now.

Comment: are you wanting an if statement.

Comment: Exactly. Just an IF statement when the subdirectory contains a specific 'string'.

Comment: what do you want to trigger the if.

Comment: Do you mean if directory = yourpath goto some ware.

Comment: the if statement should trigger a bowtie2 command (but I already have that one).

Comment: so How I see it:  Loop through a directory (that contains +- 260 other directories), if one directory contains '_L001': doOtherCommand, if directory does not contain '_L001' do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/R` (search) and `/D` (match directories) together.

```
FOR /R C:\dir\to\search /D %%d IN (*_L001) DO @ECHO Found Match: %%d
```

AFAIK, there's no such IF operator that will tell you if a path refers to a directory. You'd (probably) have to write your own.

Comment: thanks to you I figured it out; FOR /d %%d in (directory\*R1*) do echo 'Hello'